# Invoking application API on file change in Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement where-in.

1. A file will be uploaded to Google storage bucket.
2. On file change we have to invoke an API with the file name which got uploaded.

How this can be achieved.? I went through Google pub/sub or cloud functions didn't get much.

Comment: On file change?? change where?

Comment: The Google Cloud Storage event "Finalize" do exactly that. What's your challenge?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere., I am new to this world., So trying to understand what all needs to be used to achieve this behavior. Kind of a blueprint what all has to be implemented

Answer (score 1):

You should add the Object Finalize event. This event triggers when a new object is created in the bucket (or an existing object is overwritten, and a new generation of that object is created).

You can read more about this topic in [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#finalize) link.

Comment: @Eduardooritz.,
Could you please help me to understand the whole process.? 

How this finailize event notifies to my code running on GKE .? Do i have to write some code for this.?